# For loop return to previous for validation

Tags: java, validation

I'm making an Earliest Deadline Algorithm and I need a validation. I have a for loop which accepts 3 inputs, for example if I enter first these values which are arrival time, burst time and deadline:

```
5 5 10
```

and the next values are

```
0 1 20
```

What I need is to validate if the second input for arrival time is lower than the previous input. If so, it will output an error message and it will again enable me to enter values for second job. It will continue doing this until it sees a valid input.

```
for(int m=1;m<=n;m++)
{
    System.out.println("enter arrival time, burst time and deadline of process "+(m)+"(0 for none):");
    arrival[m]=sc.nextInt();
    burst[m]=sc.nextInt();
    deadline[m]=sc.nextInt();
}
```

Comment: Added the java tag to your question based on the usage of System.out, but please always tag your questions with the programming language. Nobody care about "loops", "for-loop" or "return" - the language is the most important tag for any question.

Comment: So what's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Store your old value (`v` in the sample) and compare it to the new one (`vn` in the sample):

```
class Values {
  public final int arrival;
  public final int burst;
  public final int deadline;

  public Values(int a, int b, int d) {
    this.arrival = a;
    this.burst = b;
    this.deadline = d;
  }
}

Values v = new Values(Integer.MIN_VALUE, Integer.MIN_VALUE,
    Integer.MIN_VALUE);
Values vn;
do {
  vn = new Values(sc.nextInt(), sc.nextInt(), sc.nextInt());
} while (vn.arrival < v.arrival);
```

Comment: first question how can I make it to loop for a specific number of times, and where should I put an error message. Sorry I'm still confused with the loop statements.

Comment: `for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)` loops for `n` times with `i` as a counter. However, I cannot see how this relates to your code snippet. `while` and `do`-`while` loops loop based on a condition.

Answer (score 0):

To do a quick resume, you could do something like this.
Let's say you read the values from console.

```
int[] array = new int[2];
try {
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    for (int j = 0; j < array.length ; j++) {
            int k = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
            array[j] = k;
            if((j == 1) && (array[j] > array[j-1])) {
              System.out.printLn("Burst time must be lower than arrival time");
              j--;
            }

    }
 }

catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
 }
```

Comment: so this is what I came up with after I look up from your answer

for (int m=0; m<n; m++) {
            System.out.println("enter arrival time, burst time and deadline of process "+(m+1)+"(0 for none):");
            int k=arrival[m];
            arrival[m]=sc.nextInt();
            burst[m]=sc.nextInt();
            deadline[m]=sc.nextInt();
            array[m] = k;
            if((m==1)&&(array[m]>array[m-1])) {
              System.out.println("arrival time is lower than the previous job's arrival time");
              m--;
            }
        }

Comment: What happens is it still shows an error message even though the second value was higher than the previous one

Comment: Modify to if((m==1)&&(array[m]<array[m-1]))  , i got it wrong there i guess

Comment: I already did that, but what happens is it only does check for the process which have the error on first. But for next jobs with lower value then the error won't appear again.

Comment: and oh, the while loop was just the same as 
if(arrival[m]>array[m-1])